# Powershell Test-Path Not returning correct result

Tags: powershell

Hello if i run the following command I get a response of TRUE which is correct

```
Test-Path -Path "\\LT609247\c$\Users\*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\*Internet Calendar*.pst"
```

However when I run the following commad in a script I get two FALSE returns. The iCalendar_Audit.csv contains two workstations one of which is LT609247.

```
$Computers = Get-Content c:\temp\iCalendar_Audit.csv

ForEach ($Computer in $Computers)

    { $ADComputer = $null

    $ADComputer = Get-ADComputer $Computer

    If ($ADComputer)

        { 

        Add-Content c:\temp\iCalendar_Audit.log -Value "Found $Computer, checking for iCalendar"

        Test-Path -Path "\\$ADComputer\c$\Users\*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\*Internet Calendar*.pst"

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`$ADComputer` will be an object, with several properties.. **not** a string with computer name. Assuming that `$Computer` is the computer name, you could either use `$Computer` like so -

```
Test-Path -Path "\\$Computer\c$\Users\*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\*Internet Calendar*.pst"
```

Or, if `$Computer` is not the name of the computer, check the properties of `$ADComputer` object, in the interactive shell, and find the appropriate one, which is the name of the computer. (Could be `$ADComputer.Name` for example.

Comment: Yes, or he could do: $ADComputer = Get-ADComputer $Computer | Select -Expand DNSHostName